# Importing classes from jar file in grails

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I have downloaded and copied the http-builder-0.5.0-RC2.jar to the lib folder of my grails project.  I am using GGTS and see the jar in my lib folder when I open the project.

BuildConfig.groovy has the following line in the dependency section:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0-RC2'
```

When I try to reference a class from the jar the I am getting a reference error indicating the class name cannot be resolved.

Is there something I am missing in regards to importing classes from a jar file?  I am new to java / groovy and would appreciate some help.  Thanks.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
```

This results in:

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have downloaded and copied the http-builder-0.5.0-RC2.jar to the lib folder of my grails project.

This should not be necessary, since HttpBuilder is in Maven Central.  Just declare the dependency and let Grails download the JAR itself along with its transitive dependencies.  You may also want to consider using a more recent version of HttpBuilder (0.5.0-RC2 is from 2009, at the time of writing the current release is 0.7.1).

Delete the JAR from your lib directory and try refreshing your Grails dependencies again.

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds ;)  To refresh the dependencies right-click on the project node on the left and click Grails Tools > Refresh Dependencies

Comment: I am now using the latest and refreshed my dependencies and saw that they newer files were downloaded.  Still getting a reference error when I try to import that class

Comment: Should it appear in my class path?